# Highlight active link using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how to make a link on a navigation menu stay selected when you have clicked on it? A good tutorial or example would be nice:)

Comment: Does it take you to another page, or do you stay on the same page? Can you show some HTML?

Comment: Please clarify, does the whole page reload and you want that link be highlighted afterwards or does it dynamic load content at some other part?

Comment: If you're going to another page this has nothing to do with jQuery. The solution is generating the correct code from the server.

Answer (score 1):

I happen to have some computer codes that do exactly this.

```
a.selected {
  background-color:#1F75CC;
  color:white;
}

$("a").live('click', function() {
  $("a").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use in this link [apycom.com](http://apycom.com/).
i'm a newbie too.and i have used this for my page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href="'+window.location.href+'"]').addClasss('currentPage');
```

This should do the trick. The condition is to have full path.

However, the right way is to generate correct code from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
$(".ui-accordion-content-active ul li a[href$='" + pathname + "']")
```