# Changing Color When Clicked

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, onclick, hover

I wanted to change the color of a hyperlink when it's clicked.

I used the following code and it worked:

```
var current = "home";

function home()
{
    current = "home";
    update2();
}

function comp()
{
    current = "comp";
    update2();
}

function team()
{
    current = "team";
    update2();
}

function cars()
{
    current = "cars";
    update2();
}

function spons()
{
    current = "spons";
    update2();
}

function update2()
{
    if (current == "home"){
        document.getElementById('home').style.cssText='color:#FFE006;font-size:20pt;text-   shadow: -1px 1px 8px #ff9c00, 1px -1px 8px #ff9c00;';
        document.getElementById('comp').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
        document.getElementById('team').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
        document.getElementById('cars').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
        document.getElementById('spons').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
    } else if (current == "comp"){
        document.getElementById('home').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
        document.getElementById('comp').style.cssText='color:#FFE006;font-size:20pt;text-shadow: -1px 1px 8px #ff9c00, 1px -1px 8px #ff9c00;';
        document.getElementById('team').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
        document.getElementById('cars').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
        document.getElementById('spons').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
     } else if (current == "team"){
         document.getElementById('home').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
         document.getElementById('comp').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
         document.getElementById('team').style.cssText='color:#FFE006;font-size:20pt;text-shadow:  -1px 1px 8px #ff9c00, 1px -1px 8px #ff9c00;';
         document.getElementById('cars').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
         document.getElementById('spons').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
     } else if (current == "cars"){
         document.getElementById('home').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
         document.getElementById('comp').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
         document.getElementById('team').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
         document.getElementById('cars').style.cssText='color:#FFE006;font-size:20pt;text-shadow: -1px 1px 8px #ff9c00, 1px -1px 8px #ff9c00;';
         document.getElementById('spons').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
     } else if (current == "spons"){
         document.getElementById('home').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
         document.getElementById('comp').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
         document.getElementById('team').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
         document.getElementById('cars').style.cssText='color:white;font-size:18pt;text-shadow:;';
         document.getElementById('spons').style.cssText='color:#FFE006;font-size:20pt;text-shadow: -1px 1px 8px #ff9c00, 1px -1px 8px #ff9c00;';
     }
 }
```

Actually, it worked but a problem arose. As you can see, that I tried to change the properties such as color, size and text shadow when `current` is set to `home/spons/cars/team/comp`. `current` changes when a function is called when a user clicks on a hyperlink.

A problem appears as I told it to do the same properties when it is `:hover`. Once a button is clicked, its properties are changed, and so are the other hyperlinks, to white color and 18 pt size.

Now, once the user clicks on a hyperlink, it changes the source of a frame, its own properties and other hyperlinks' properties. But once I click it and then hover onto another hyperlink, the properties of hovering don't work but the properties of the javascript work.

If you can't understand my problem then take look at http://www.xphoenix1.hpage.com/ . Once one menu button is clicked, it changes other buttons properties too and stop the hover properties.

If you are able to understand what I'm saying and have a solution to it, then please answer.

Thank You in advance

Comment: Isn't `a:visited {color:red}` enough for you ? Why ?

Comment: That solution is like building a ladder out of angry kittens to scale a wall when there's already a door.

Comment: And **that** is why some people think JavaScript is evil.

Answer (score 1):

In fairness to the OP, they wanted to affect some changes that were more than just text color. And, unfortunately, most [styling of the :visited state no longer works as it once did](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/).

In addition to the font color, they're also making the font size a little bigger and adding/removing a text shadow.

Though, I agree, this JS approach is a bit over the top.

My suggestion to the OP is have the menu links actually go to separate pages, not just swap out divs. You could then move a "current" class move from link to link by whatever means you wish - even by hand if this is static HTML. Then just style it accordingly:

```
a.current {  //styles }
```

This way introduces a lot less possibility for things to go wrong, and the navigation would work only with HTML & CSS - no JS required.

Comment: This was what I thought before starting this experimental website having just one page. I knew that there could be some problem in making a website whose navigation menu's hyperlinks change just the source of an iframe, but i wanted to experiment. Please tell me if there is any way to solve this or i'll have to leave this crazy idea. Actually my website does't require js for changing pages but only showing the current in a different manner

Comment: a:visited ain't enough because my hyperlinks are actually buttons of the menu of my website xphoenix1.hpage.com. They change the source of the iframe below them and I don't want the colour to be changed for always but until another button isn't clicked.

Comment: Can you tell me a way to completely change the class of an <a> in js

Comment: In general, I would steer you away from the frame-based approach that you're using on the site. I understand you want to experiment, but there are some significant downsides to this approach - visitors cannot bookmark any particular sections, and search engines might not be able to index your content. As for swapping classes on a particular link, you might have to alter your markup a bit, but something like this approach would work: http://rockycode.com/blog/addremove-classes-raw-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

this is simple in css

```
a:hover{background-color:yellow;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write text color for hyperlink, write like this

```
a:visited{
    color:red;
    }
```

Updated:

Ok got it, if you want to use JQuery, the idea is that you will have the menu as `<li>` or  or any other element and these images as a background image. when you create pics have both the white color text & yellow colored one below other (CSS spriting), onclick of the menu you add a class called selected to the current element and move the image above so the yellow color text will show, then remove selected class from all other menus. for example i have used `<a>` tag for example.

```
.menu a{
   background-image:url('images/button.png');
}
.menu a.selected {
     background-image:url('images/button.png'):0 -50px;
}

$(".menu a").live('click', function() {
  $(".menu a").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");
  return false;
});
```

check this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465248/highlight-active-link-using-jquery)

Comment: a:visited ain't enough because my hyperlinks are actually buttons of the menu of my website http://www.xphoenix1.hpage.com/. They change the source of the iframe below them and I don't want the colour to be changed for always but until another button isn't clicked.

Comment: Can you tell me a way to completely change the class of an <a> in js

Comment: @XPhoenix In JQuery you can do that through .addClass() method, sorry dont know for js.

Comment: found it in js- document.getElementById('id').className = 'class';

Answer (score 0):

Then use

```
#home:visited, #comp:visited{
    color:red;
}
```

or better, apply all the relevant anchors with a className, e.g. 'rav' (red after visited ;))
so you can do:

```
.rav:visited{ color:red; }
```

Cheers!

Comment: actually i am using .btns:(state) as told by your 2nd code, but visited is not the solution as the hyperlinks are buttons for my website http://www.xphoenix1.hpage.com/ and change the source of an iframe that is under the buttons and visited won't remove their extra style once i click on another hyperlink

Comment: Can you tell me a way to completely change the class of an <a> in js

Comment: Sure, you can use jQuery toggleClass() (http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/). $("#home").toggleClass("yourClassName") applies it when not applied, or removes it when applied.